# Can I get a closed form of this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, closed-form, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

$$\begin{array}{ll} 
& \underset{w \in \mathbb R^n}{\text{minimize}}
& &  \quad w^{H} w \\ 
& \text{subject to}
& &   w^{H} A w \geq 1 \\
& & & w^{H} B w \geq 1 \end{array} \\$$

where $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite. Can I get a closed-form expression for the optimal $w$?

Comment: short answer: no